# flutter Scroll TextField when cursor goes under keyboard so it is shown

Tags: flutter

I want to have a whole page for entering text (such notes).
I use a TextField but when the text is too long, it goes under the keyboard.
I want the widget to scroll so the cursor is above the keyboard.

So far I tried the following but the cursor is always above keyboard and not just when needed.

(this part is in a column: )

```
 Expanded(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            physics: const ClampingScrollPhysics(),
            reverse: true,
            controller: _scrollController,
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom),
              child: TextField(
                controller: _textEditingController,
                selectionControls: MaterialTextSelectionControls(),
                focusNode: _focusNode,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                maxLines: null,
                autofocus: true,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(border: InputBorder.none),
                onChanged: (value) {
                  newDescription = value.trim();
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

How can I scroll it to be shown above the keyboard when needed?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I managed to overcome it.
The problem was I put in a ModalBottomSheet.
Once I moved it into Scaffold, it was ok and the cursor did not go down under the keyboard.